# Can Mysql cache calls to same function with same arguments

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

For example I have this condition

```
WHERE f1=CONCAT(v1,v2) OR f2=CONCAT(v1,v2) -- /*...
```

where v1,v1 are static, then Mysql must cache result of concat after first call.
If v1 is field, then Mysql must cache result of concat after first call, but only for current row.

So, Mysql doing this?

Answer (score 2):

No, MySQL does not cache function calls.

Furthermore, such an optimization would not be worth doing.  Note the tiny difference:

```
mysql> SELECT city, country, CONCAT(city, country) FROM cities LIMIT 263000,5
+----------+---------+-----------------------+
| city     | country | CONCAT(city, country) |
+----------+---------+-----------------------+
| Kitanzi  | cg      | Kitanzicg             |
| Masend   | cg      | Masendcg              |
| Chilute  | ao      | Chiluteao             |
| Khilule  | ao      | Khiluleao             |
| Tchibuti | ao      | Tchibutiao            |
+----------+---------+-----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.10 sec)

mysql> SELECT city, country FROM cities LIMIT 263000, 5;
+----------+---------+
| city     | country |
+----------+---------+
| Kitanzi  | cg      |
| Masend   | cg      |
| Chilute  | ao      |
| Khilule  | ao      |
| Tchibuti | ao      |
+----------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Fetching the rows is more costly than any function calls in the expressions.

You can, however, use @variables to do the caching yourself.  Again, you won't gain much, if any, speed.  (However, you might gain simplicity in your code.)

Comment: Any idea on how to explain this behaviour: `select rand(1), rand(1) from dual where rand(1) = 0.40540353712197724` - http://rextester.com/LNMRH88059 ?

Comment: `RAND()` and `RAND(value)` are different.  The former always gives a different random number; the latter converts `value` to something random -- but is repeatable.

Comment: Rick, i was looking for a way to validate or invalidate your statement. So my question is: Why does `RAND(1)` return the same value for [each row](http://rextester.com/FIQM84485) even in the WHERE clause. However i now believe that the behaviour of `RAND(1)` has nothing to do with cache.

Comment: [_Ref manual_](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) - "With a constant initializer, the seed is initialized once when the statement is compiled, prior to execution. If a nonconstant initializer (such as a column name) is used as the argument, the seed is initialized with the value for each invocation of RAND(). (One implication of this is that for equal argument values, RAND() will return the same value each time.)"

Comment: Put another way...  Certain functions, such as `NOW()`, are _deliberately_ evaluated only once per statement.  I guess `RAND(1)` falls into that category.

Comment: OK - i've tested with the `sha2()` function. Now i'm pretty sure no cache is used.

Comment: Perhaps my Comments about `RAND(1)` should have said `RAND()`.