# MySQL Performance - Sub Query vs Custom Function

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have been using the same subquery to check the specific functionality in many SQLs. e.g. a complex user permission checking.

In this case, which one is better among using that subquery and using the custom function in performance?

The subquery is the following:

```
(SELECT 1 FROM `perm_categories_map` WHERE whatever={parentTable.whatever} AND category_id={Constant})
```

and its usage example is

```
... AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `perm_categories_map` WHERE whatever={parentTable.whatever} AND category_id={Constant}) ...
```

I am going to make a function called `check_perm` so that I can call like `... AND check_perm({parentTable.whatever}, {constant})  ...`

But before doing it, I'd like to confirm that function is faster than subquery from a performance perspective.

I would think function is faster than the subquery.  What's your opinion?

Comment: I am not sure. It depends on entire SQL? Generally, function isn't faster, is it? My sub query is ```EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `perm_categories_map` WHERE whatever={parentTable.whatever} AND category_id={Constant})```

Comment: @ysth, thanks for your answer. I thought that function is faster because may be cached. At least, a SQL in function is saving syntax parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXISTS(SELECT 1 ... )
```

is a special construct called a "semi-join".  It says "perform the following SELECT *but* stop at soon as you find a match."

Any other use of that same "subquery" (`(SELECT 1 ... )`) will run to completion, potentially producing multiple rows, each with `1` in it.

So, `EXISTS` is faster, at least in some situations.

Think of `EXISTS` as a boolean function returning TRUE/FALSE (or, equivalently, 1/0).  Also the `1` in side the `SELECT` can be anything.

MariaDB has a subquery cache; MySQL does not.

There may be some caching of the "parsing" in stored routines (see `PREPARE` and its friends), but not in stand-alone queries.

Answer (score 1):

Which one performs better for you?  Without seeing your code, no one will be able to tell you.  If your function is just doing that exact same query, I wouldn't think the function would be any faster, unless the subquery is somehow causing your entire query to be misoptimized.  Try it and see is the only real answer.  There isn't any caching of function results that would make them any faster; even built in functions aren't cached, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33060896.